# Google Play store is showing error about signed apk

Tags: android, google-play, sign

I am getting the following error when trying to upload my apk:

> You uploaded an APK that is signed with a key that is also used to sign APKs that are delivered to users. Because you are enrolled in App Signing, you should sign your APK with a new key before you upload it.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Have you tried signing you APK with a new key before you upload it?

Answer (score 0):

As it is showing you have enabled App Signing from Google Play Console so follow the instructions there and you have to create to new keystore to create the upload certificate so use that same keystore file to sign your APK in your build.gradle file as well.